# boost::thread segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I have Runnable class. In which, following functions I use to start new thread:

```
      start()
      {
           status_ = RUNNING;
            mythread_ = boost::thread(boost::ref(*this)); // Line 2
      }
```

I have Controller class derived from Runnable.
and I want to create thread for Controller using start() function

So, In Controller start function,

I use:

```
controller_->start()
```

to create a new thread;

But which eventually leads to segmentation fault at Line 2.

Any idea what could have been gone wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, assuming `controller_` is a valid object, the class has an `operator()()`, and your real code includes the missing return type and semicolon.

Comment: There's a good chance controller_ is not a valid pointer

Answer (score 0):

I remember sometimes not specifying the thread library to the compiler has resulted in segfault. Try adding -pthread argument to the compiler if you're using unix. It seems though that it's not needed on latest linux/boost/gcc anymore.

Comment: Thanks kynnysmatto, I have included pthread. I think it is not able to resolve *this properly. how can I use "this" reference of controller class in start method??

Comment: I don't know. This works at least on my computer: [http://pastebin.com/LtfCnrBK](http://pastebin.com/LtfCnrBK)

Comment: Thanks. Wrong file was included "boost/thread/thread.hpp" but has to be "boost/thread.hpp"

Answer (score 0):

The object's address is only available from within the member function as the `this` pointer and most uses of `this` are implicit.

Alternatively, you can make the `start()` function, `friend` of the class and directly sending reference of the object to your new thread.